# AngularJs Binding questions

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get number of rows from the text that gets inject into text area, for some reason I can't get textarea to initalize number of row, here's my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <textarea contenteditable="true" 
                  rows="'iwofRecord.WhatHasBeenDone.split('\n').lenght'" 
                  class="form-control form-control-plain" 
                  ng-model="iwofRecord.WhatHasBeenDone" 
                  placeholder="What Has Been Done">
        </textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rows` is not an Angular attribute, wrap that in `{{}}` - you're also double quoting that attribute (and have `length` spelled wrong)

```
rows="{{iwofRecord.WhatHasBeenDone.split('\n').length}}"
```

Comment: You're awesome and I am such an immigrant :-)!

Answer (score 2):

`.lengHT` - there is a typo, it has to be `.length`

Comment: You're awesome and I am such an immigrant :-)!